# Creating texture from RGB

Tags: qt, opengl, qt4, qt5

I am receiving an screen-shot Palette over the network. Next, I convert the Palette indices to their relevant RGB using my matrix containing different colors.

The problem I have with the code is I cannot create a texture out of this RGB image I receive successfully.

```
oid GlWidget::createTextureFromBitmap(QByteArray btmp)
{
 tex.buf = new unsigned char[bytes.size()];
memcpy(tex.buf, bytes.constData(), bytes.size());
glGenTextures( 1, &tex.id);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex.id);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glTexImage2D(     GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 0, 0, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex.buf);
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, 800, 600, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex.buf);
delete [] tex.buf;
tex.buf = NULL;

updateGL();
}

void GlWidget::paintGL()
{
 shaderProgram.bind();
shaderProgram.setUniformValue("mvpMatrix", pMatrix * vMatrix * mMatrix);
shaderProgram.setUniformValue("texture", 0);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex.id);
//glActiveTexture(0);

shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("vertex", vertices.constData());
shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("vertex");
shaderProgram.setAttributeArray("textureCoordinate", textureCoordinates.constData());
shaderProgram.enableAttributeArray("textureCoordinate");

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.size());

shaderProgram.disableAttributeArray("vertex");
shaderProgram.disableAttributeArray("textureCoordinate");
shaderProgram.release();
}
```

Comment: What has this to do with Qt?

Answer (score 1):

```
  glTexImage2D(     GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 0, 0, 0, GL_RGB, GL_3_BYTES, tex.buf);
  gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, 800, 600, GL_RGB, GL_3_BYTES, tex.buf);
```

`GL_3_BYTES` is not a valid data type here, you prpbably mean `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`. Apart from that, there are some redundant calls here. Your `glTexImage2D`  call will specify the data for mipmap level 0, the `gluBuild2DMipmaps` will specify all the mipmap levels, *including* 0. Since you use mipmapping, you will only need the latter of those calls. But both calls will fail with `GL_INVALID_ENUM` due to the wrong data type, so you don't have any texture. So you can replace that two lines by:

```
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, 800, 600, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex.buf);
```

Another thing:

```
glActiveTexture(0);
```

this is also invalid. Only the `GL_TEXTUREn` values are valid for that call. You also do not need to "disable" the active texture selector, as you might try to do here. It will *always* point to some valid texture unit.

Comment: Could you please replace your modification in the main code above. because I am not very familiar to GL programming and don't know exactly what things to replace to the segments become correct.

Comment: @user1596226: I updated my answer. Thr `glActiveTexture(0);` line is completele unnecessary. But you won't get very far if you don't learn the basics first...

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution does not output the texture. I updated the code above, can you please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the fixes mentioned above, you can improve the performance by not having to do an additional memcopy (1 in your code, 1 in GL driver), by sending the palette also as a texture, then doing the same indexing that you are doing in the CPU code, inside the shader code. Also, if you are anyway setting the `bytes[]` array, no need to clear the array first.